# Cython C compilation on windows

Tags: python, c, gcc, cython

I've written a simple python script, compiled it to C using Cython and then tried to compile it using gcc (mingw on windows):

```
gcc -shared -I c:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/include/ -L  c:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/libs/ -l python36 check.c
```

The compilation produced some warnings:

```
c:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/include/pytime.h:112:5: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list
     _PyTime_round_t round);
     ^
c:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/include/pytime.h:112:5: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
c:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/include/pytime.h:117:5: warning: 'struct timeval' declared inside parameter list
     _PyTime_round_t round);
```

But the linkage produced many errors of missing functions:

```
C:\Users\OMOSEN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2oMDoi.o:check.c:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_New'
C:\Users\OMOSEN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2oMDoi.o:check.c:(.text+0xe7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyBytes_FromStringAndSize'
C:\Users\OMOSEN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2oMDoi.o:check.c:(.text+0x136): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize'
```

...

I've tried to use the -DMS_WIN64 flag but it didn't help...

Please help, thanks...

Comment: You may need to use the `-lpython36` option. No space. The option with as space is not recommended.

Comment: thanks but same effect also without the space...

Comment: Does c:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/include/ contain `libpython36.a` or `python36.a`? Because that's what the `-l` option will try to link against

Comment: oops.. no, only python3.lib and python36.lib.. I don't see any .a in my installation.

Comment: Then try `-l python36.lib` with the space

Comment: It seems it can't find it:
c:/mingw1/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpython36.lib

Comment: What option did you specify precisely?

Comment: That's the command I've used:
gcc -shared -I c:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/include/ -L  c:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/libs/ -l python36.lib check.c

Comment: If I understand correctly, using the previous version, let the linker find python3.lib but it didn't contain the necessary functions. I'm starting to think it might be an issue of architecture: I'm running it on a 64bit machine and the python version I've installed might not support it?

Comment: Quite possibly. To be frank, there's too much that is variable for a definitive answer IMO

Comment: I see. Anyhow, I really appreciate your attempt to help. A big, big thank you!